# Created m2m fields values are assigned to all existing users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I try to create a user profile with a many to many relation.
Those are my models:

```py
class Job(models.Model):
    CARRYING = 'carrying'
    CARRYING_FOR_MOVE_TOOLS = 'carrying_for_move_tools'
    CHOICES = [
        (CARRYING, 'yyyyyyyyy'),
        (CARRYING_FOR_MOVE_TOOLS, 'xxxxxxxxxx'),
     ]

     job = models.CharField(max_length=1000,
                            choices=CHOICES, 
                            primary_key=True,
                            default='',
                            unique=True)
    display_sort_key = models.FloatField(default=0.)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_job_display()

    def get_slug_prefix(self):
        return self.SLUG_PREFIX[self.job]


class Userprofile(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    jobs = models.ManyToManyField(Job)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

When i create Jobs in the admnin panel or send the jobs via the client interface (Angular), all created jobs are assigned to all existing userprofiles.

How can i create a Jobs in Django admin panel without those jobs are assign to the all existing userprofiles?
or
How can i assign in Django Admin panel the Jobs-data send from Angular only to the userprofile of the logged user ?

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: Hi @SunderamDubey, the question is correctly formated now.